# How to calculate distance between cluster centres of kmeans and choose the minimum in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have ran a kmeans algorithm using `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`, where I save the results in the object `kmeans_results`

I can do `cl_centers = kmeans_results.cluster_centers_` in order to obtain the cluster centers.

`cl_centers` look like this:

```
array([[0.69332691, 0.9118433 , 0.14215727, 0.00903798],
       [0.41407049, 0.95964501, 0.19565154, 0.03157038],
       [0.88239715, 0.65602688, 0.20304053, 0.01066663],
       [0.65413307, 0.92372214, 0.36504241, 0.03482278]])
```

I would like to calculate the in between distance of these 4 points, and choose the smallest one, together with their "labels" (where label is just the array index).

The ideal output would be something like:

"The smallest distance is x, and it occurs between cluster 0 and cluster 3"

By "distance" I mean Euclidean distance

Is there a pythonic way of doing this ?

Comment: When you say “pythonic” what you had in mine, a one-liner?

Comment: without the use of a for loop

Comment: Hi, you can try `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(your_array)` which gives you distance matrix between points

Comment: @zelenovaleksey You can post it as an answer :)

Comment: @quant done, please mark it as an answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can try `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(your_array)` which gives you distance matrix between points. Then get your minimal distance

Answer (score 3):

The solution to your problem consists of 2 parts.

1. calculate the pair-wise distance matrix of the `cl_centers` array.
2. Find the indices of the minimum position.

So as @zelenov aleksey suggested for the first part, the [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) will calculate the pair-wise distances.
and then you can create a list of combination of pairwise indices to select from using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

The following will give you the ideal output you stated in your question:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
import itertools as it

centers_arr = np.array([[0.69332691, 0.9118433 , 0.14215727, 0.00903798],
       [0.41407049, 0.95964501, 0.19565154, 0.03157038],
       [0.88239715, 0.65602688, 0.20304053, 0.01066663],
       [0.65413307, 0.92372214, 0.36504241, 0.03482278]])

pairs = list(it.combinations(range(4),2))

d = pdist(centers_arr)
print("The smallest distance is {:}, and it occurs between cluster {:} and cluster {:}".format(d.min(), *pairs[d.argmin(axis=0)]))
```